# Change in behavior of popToViewController on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios8

IOS 7 popToViewController, and earlier, returns the list of popped off controllers as a return value. But on iOS 8 beta 5 it returns nil. This is not good for my app. Anyone else know about this change in behavior? Looks like a bug to me, but is anyone aware of an intentional change here?

```
NSArray *controllers = [self.navigationController **popToViewController:self** animated:NO];
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue even on iOS8.0.2. Have you been able to get any sort of resolution on this?

Comment: I submitted a bug but apple wanted me to provide an app with the behavior in it. I have not had time to provide this as stripping my app down is a huge effort. Might have to start with the approach of creating a new test app, instead of stripping my app.

Comment: Yeah they always do the same exact crap an expect us to do all the work. I've had to make tons of test apps showing bugs, and most of them get completely ignored except an occasional question asking me if the bug is still present in some new iOS version. I suppose it's just way too much work for them to actually check that using the test app they asked for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was able to work around it by swapping a few lines of code. I believe this to be a bug that should be fixed by Apple, but maybe this workaround will help others out until it is fixed.

In my case the bug only occurred when calling popToViewController from an action triggered in a UIPopoverController. My handler looked like this:

```
- (void)didSelectBreadcrumbAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    [self.popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popController = nil;

    [self popToViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];
}
```

The workaround is to dismiss the popover after calling popToViewController instead of before. The handler now looks like this:

```
- (void)didSelectBreadcrumbAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    [self popToViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];

    [self.popController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popController = nil;
}
```

To be clear, "self" in this case is a class derived from UINavigationController.